# How to access XML or transform to JSON in Laravel

Tags: php, json, xml, laravel, object

I have this XML response:

```
<AuthorisationResult xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://webservice.redletterdays.co.uk/">
<RequestSuccessful>true</RequestSuccessful>
<ErrorMessage/>
<Token>3d3d4a94-87fe-414c-ae0a-fd0e0c4c0060</Token>
</AuthorisationResult>
```

[image]

That's what I got when I write:

```
return $res;
```

How can I access Token?

I try :

```
return $res->Token;
```

and also

```
return $res->children();
```

but this code returns me errors...

SO, How I can access Token in XML or how to transform into JSON and easy access to Token like $res->Token ...

Comment: Put your xml as text but not picture

Comment: I put this as a text

Comment: `$xml = simplexml_load_string($res); echo $xml->Token;`

Comment: https://eval.in/952909

Comment: I solve like: res = json_encode(simplexml_load_string($res->getBody()));
$res = json_decode($res);
$token = $res->Token;

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
$json = $res->getBody();
$array = json_decode($json);

dump($array);
```

Comment: I already try that but I got: simplexml_load_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Comment: @AleksPer in that case you already have an XML object, see my updated answer please

Comment: Yes but I got empty array , like '[ ]'

Comment: @AleksPer how are you getting the `$res` object?

Comment: I get $res object from API as a response

Comment: @AleksPer what does `echo $res->asXML();` output?

Comment: Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response::asXML()

Comment: I got: Object of class GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response could not be converted to string

Comment: @AleksPer ah, finally just try `$json = $res->getBody()->getContents();` and try to dump $json

Comment: Yes, I got XML file as a string but how to access to TOKEN ?

Comment: @AleksPer try removing TRUE from json_decode, see my update

Comment: I try but wont work again... again I got null... Do you have TW ?

Comment: @AleksPer I've no idea why it's not working!, finally try with the updated answer

Comment: the closes solution for this is :         $result =  json_decode(json_encode($res->getBody()->getContents()));

    return response()->json(['data' => $result]);

Comment: then I got something like: {"data":"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\r\n<AuthorisationResult xmlns:xsi=\"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2001\/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2001\/XMLSchema\" xmlns=\"http:\/\/webservice.rasdasdasd.co.uk\/\">\r\n  <RequestSuccessful>true<\/RequestSuccessful>\r\n  <ErrorMessage \/>\r\n  <Token>8ef17eb5-7c0f-49a0-a673-9999999\/Token>\r\n<\/AuthorisationResult>"}

Answer (score 1):

I solve my problem with:

```
$res = json_encode(simplexml_load_string($res->getBody()));
$res = json_decode($res);
$token = $res->Token;
```